# How can I use an if-else statement to select elements in different matrices?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have been stuck on the following issue for days and would appreciate any help. I have 2 different matrices, A and B. I have a starting x and y position (xpos, ypos), and want to first, identify whether there is an element within a certain range that has a value of "0" in the matrix B. If there is an element of such kind, I want the x and y position of this element to be the new x and y position. If there aren't any elements with a value of "0", I want to select the element with the highest value within a certain range from the starting positions in matrix A. The position and this element then becomes the new x and y position. I have the following code:

```
for i=1:5
    range=5
    xpos=100
    ypos=100
    xstart=xpos-range
    ystart=ypos-range

    for gg=1:10; %double the range
        for hh=1:10;

            if  ystart+gg <= 652 && ystart+gg>0 && xstart+hh <= 653 &&  xstart+hh> 0 &&  B(xstart+hh,ystart+gg)== 0;

                xpos = xstart+hh %this becomes the new xposition
                ypos = ystart+gg

            else

                if  ystart+gg <= 652 && ystart+gg >0 && xstart+hh <= 653 && xstart + hh >0 && B(xstart+hh,ystart+gg)~= 0;

                    if  ystart+gg <= 652 && ystart +gg>0 && xstart+hh <= 653 && xstart+hh>0 && A(ystart + gg, xstart +hh) >= 0.0;
                        maxtreecover = A(ystart + gg, xstart + hh)

                        xpos = xstart + gg %this becomes the new xpos
                        ypos = ystart + hh %this becomes the new ypos

                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The problem with this is that it does not search ALL of the elements within the range for a "0" (in the B matrix) before moving into searching the A matrix. How can I modify this code to reflect what I intend it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a re-write of your code which avoids the double loop. I assume all of your `if` conditions are so that the index remains valid (between 1 and the size of the matrix), but they wouldn't work in their current form because the indexing is done in the same line anyway! I've also addressed this using `min` and `max` conditions on `xpos` and `ypos`.

This solution gets the submatrix which spans +/- the range from your `xpos` and `ypos`. Then it evaluates the 2 conditions you describe within that submatrix:

- Get the position of the first element of `B` which is zero
- Get the position of the maximum element of A

Code is commented for details:

```
% Create matrices A and B
n = 100; % Size of matrices
A = rand(n);
B = rand(n);
range = 5;            % "radius" of submatrix
xpos = 50; ypos = 50; % start point

% Iterate
for ii = 1:5
    % Get submatrices around xpos and ypos, using min and max to ensure valid
    subx = max(1,xpos-range):min(n,xpos+range);
    suby = max(1,ypos-range):min(n,ypos+range);
    A_sub = A(suby, subx);
    B_sub = B(suby, subx);
    % Find first 0 in submatrix of B, re-assign xpos/ypos if so
    [yidx, xidx] = find(B_sub == 0, 1);
    if ~isempty(xidx)
        xpos = subx(xidx);
        ypos = suby(yidx);
    else
        % Get max from submatrix of A
        [~, idx] = max(A_sub(:));
        [xidx, yidx] = meshgrid(subx, suby);
        xpos = xidx(idx);
        ypos = yidx(idx);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Still trying to understand this all, but why does "find(B_sub ==0,1)" have the "0,1"? Why doesn't "find(B_sub == 0)" suffice?

Comment: No problem... `B_sub == 0` is the condition we want to *`find`*, so that explains the `0`! Then the `1` means you're only interested in the first match. So if the submatrix has 5 zeros, it will only return the index of the first one. This is because we can only re-assign `xpos` and `ypos` to one value each!

Comment: Also apologies for my lazy variable naming, I think my use of "rows" and "cols" might have made things confusing. There was also a typo after the `~isempty` line. I have updated my code for better clarity, and it seems to work as expected in tests. Any queries let me know...

Comment: Thank you, I did! Can you please briefly explain how the "if ~isempty(xidx)" works? I see that it is meant to find the first zero, but I can't figure out why only mention the "xidx" and not the "yidx".

Comment: no worries, this code is a lot more sophisticated (elegant may be the word) than the one I currently have so apologies for the questions that likely have obvious answers!

Comment: If there are any zeros in `B_sub`, then `find(B_sub==0,1)` will return the row and column index of the first one, which I have assigned to `yidx` and `xidx` respectively. If there is no zero element, then `find` will return **both** of `yidx` and `xidx` as an empty array (`[ ]`). It's impossible for one to be empty and not the other, so no point checking both. The tilde (`~`) means "not", so in summary, by checking "if `xidx` isn't empty" I'm actually checking if the `find` statement returned anything and so there is a zero